# Moment generating function from probability mass function

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

We are given the pmf: $$f_X(k) = \frac{1}{k(k+1)}, k \geq 1 $$ and we have to compute the moment generating function. So far I've got:
$$M_X(t) = E[e^{tx}] = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{tk} \frac{1}{k(k+1)}$$
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k(k+1)}$ is a telescoping sequence right that equals to 1?
So how do I move forward from here?

Comment: I don't believe the moment generating function exists as the  series  diverges  for any $t\neq0$. That i s  the exponential growth of $e^{tk}$  grows   faster then $\frac{1}{k(k+1)}$  decays.

Comment: You could  try using the  taylor series  expansion of $e^{tk}$

Answer (score 2):

First, assume that $t<0$ since otherwise the series clearly diverges. Then, note that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty e^{tk}=\dfrac{1}{1-e^t}$, by geometric series. Now, consider the integral of both sides over $t$
$$
\begin{align*}
\int \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty e^{tk}\, dt&= \int \dfrac{dt}{1-e^t}\\
t + \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{e^{tk}}{k}&=-\ln (1-e^t)\\
\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{e^{tk}}{k}&=-\ln (1-e^t) - t.
\end{align*}
$$

Now, we unbox your MGF.
$$
\begin{align*}
M_X(t)= \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty e^{tk}\dfrac{1}{k(k+1)}&= \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty e^{tk}\left(\dfrac{1}{k}-\dfrac{1}{k+1}\right)\\
&= \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \left(\dfrac{e^{tk}}{k}-\dfrac{e^{tk}}{k+1}\right)\\
&= \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{e^{tk}}{k}-\frac{1}{e^t}\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{e^{t(k+1)}}{k+1}\\
&= \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{e^{tk}}{k}-\frac{1}{e^t}\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty\dfrac{e^{tk}}{k}\\
&=  \left(-\ln(1-e^t)-t \right)-\frac{1}{e^t}\left(-\ln(1-e^t)-t -e^t\right)\\
& = 1+(e^{-t}-1)(\ln(1-e^t)+t).
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: doesn’t the mgf have to exist around a neighborhood of zero in order to serve its purpose evaluating derivative of mgf at t=o